# OAuth or API key authorization?

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm trining to create live stream on youtube using google API. Now it working only when I use oauth authorisation. When I use API key authorisation I get authorisation error (login required)

When I use oauth authorisation - it require to enter confirmation code each time I create new translation. Is it possible to use "liveStreams->insert" method of API with authorisation that does not require entering of confirmation code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are writing it appears to me that you haven't understood the concept of OAuth and when to use OAuth vs an API key.

Try to think about it this way: You, as a person, have a Google account. This Google account is not the same as your YouTube account (or, as it is more commonly refered to, your YouTube channel). But your Google account is associated with your YouTube channel (of which you can have multiple). Because you are logged in to your Google account and your channel and Google account are linked, the YouTube website knows who you are and gives you access to your channel.

Now you head over to the Google Cloud Console. Here you create a project, which is very similar to a YouTube account in the sense that it, too, is an independent account which in this case represents your app, but is linked to your Google account so the Cloud Console website knows to give you access to the project as long as you are logged-in to your Google account.

HOWEVER, your YouTube account is not linked to your Cloud Console project. When you make an API request with an API key, the API does not see you as in "your Google account", but rather your apps's Cloud Console Project. That's why with an API key, you can only access publicly available data (everything you could "see" when you browse YouTube while not being logged-in).

So, in order for an application to read private channel information or modify channel information, the API needs verification that whoever makes that request is actually allowed to do that. This is where OAuth comes into play.

When you say you have to provide the confirmation code for each request, I think you don't save the access token and refresh token. I highly recommend you read [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) and [Obtaining authorization credentials](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application) over on Google Developers to help get you started.

Comment: Thank you I understand it. I developing application that must automatically start from cron and create livestream based on schedule for students. So, only one way for me - is using special script for refresh token each 59 minutes (token lifetime is 3600 seconds). Correct?

Comment: Yes, using the refresh token to fetch a new access token is the normal way. You can do that at any time, you don't have to wait for the access token to expire. So this could be the first thing your script does each time it runs. It's not perfect, but it would work.